# Pandas rowwise ffilling

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to specify a ffill for an entire row? What I mean by this, is to condition on one value [Check] in the row to see if the row should be fforwardfilled.

My main goal is to keep row integrity intact (i.e. I only want to to forwardfilling an entire row into the next one). For the sake of simplicity assume that each row corresponds to an event, I want to forwardfill the data from the past event if the new event does not have data (in Val1). I do not want to mix data from past events as I forwardfill it should be noted, that nan values might be legitimate values for an event and should be forward filled as well.

**First Example**:

```
    Check   Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4
0   2.00    3.00    2.00    2.00    3.00
1   2.00    4.00    nan     3.00    4.00
2   2.00    nan     nan     nan     nan
3   2.00    2.00    4.00    3.00    3.00
```

Should become

```
    Check   Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4
0   2.00    3.00    2.00    2.00    3.00
1   2.00    4.00    nan     3.00    4.00
2   2.00    4.00    nan     3.00    4.00
3   2.00    2.00    4.00    3.00    3.00
```

and not:

```
    Check   Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4
0   2.00    3.00    2.00    2.00    3.00
1   2.00    4.00    2.00    3.00    4.00
2   2.00    4.00    2.00    3.00    4.00
3   2.00    2.00    4.00    3.00    3.00
```

**Second example:**

```
    Check   Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4
0   2.00    3.00    2.00    2.00    3.00
1   2.00    4.00    nan     3.00    4.00
2   2.00    4.00    nan     nan     nan
3   2.00    2.00    4.00    3.00    3.00
```

Should remain unchanged.

Comment: This is unclear. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52475728/edit) with a precise description of what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Use for replace only one `NaN`s per columns - replace fitst all values and then check consecutive `NaN`s, which are set by `mask` to `NaN`s:

```
df = df.ffill().mask((df.ffill(limit=1) * df.bfill(limit=1)).isnull())
print (df)
     0    1    2    3    4
0  2.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  3.0
1  2.0  4.0  NaN  3.0  4.0
2  2.0  4.0  NaN  3.0  4.0
3  2.0  2.0  4.0  3.0  3.0
```

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you need not repalce or consecutive 2 or more NaNs ?

Comment: The approach here is less columnar, but rather row wise an NaN value could be totally okay in conjunction with the  filled values in the other columns.

Comment: @FabianBosler - Sorry, dont understand.

Comment: @FabianBosler - Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?